# Call method from onSuccess to another class

Tags: java, android

I'm new with java/android development so please help if you can.

I would like to have a method which is getting me data from web service (async) and once done (onSuccess or onFailure) it should call another method on activity class.
Lets say I have WebManager class, this isn't real method, I'm going to add more still plus try/catch and so on:

```
    public class WebManager {

            public MyObject1 getObject1() {
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

                client.get(QUERY_URL,
                        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                                 //Call method on my Activity and pass jsonObject (in the other method I want to pass my custom object instead of json)
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                                //Call method on my Activity and pass statusCode, throwable and error
                            }
                        });
            }

            public MyObject2 getObject2() {
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                // The same as above
            }
        }
```

Now in my MainActivity I would like to call let's say getObject1() and when the data are download I would like to call method:

```
WebManager wm = new WebManager();
//... 


protected void onObject1DataDownload(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    //Do something with the data
}

protected void onObject2DataDownload(CUSTOMOBJECT obj) {
    //Do something with the data
}
```

How can I achieve something like that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an interface

   ```
   public interface ResponseListener {
   void onObject1DataDownload(JSONObject jsonObject);
   }
   ```
2. Change your getObject1() method inside WebManager to parameterized method, and call the callback method.

   ```
   public class WebManager {
   public MyObject1 getObject1(ResponseListener listener) {
       AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

       client.get(QUERY_URL,
               new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                        //here's the change
                        listener.onObject1DataDownload(jsonObject);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                       //Call method on my Activity and pass statusCode, throwable and error
                   }
               });
   }
   ```
3. Implement the interface in your activity

   ```
   public class MainActivity implements ResponseListener{

   public void someMethod() {
    WebManager wm = new WebManager(); 
    //pass the activity as the listener
    wm.getObject1(this);

   }
   protected void onObject1DataDownload(JSONObject jsonObject) { 
   //this method will be called }

   protected void onObject2DataDownload(CUSTOMOBJECT obj) { //Do something with the data }

   }
   ```

Similarly you can register a callback for onFailure method.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for. Just one more question, what if I want to call my method like: wm.getObject1(this, public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {//My code here});

Comment: Ohkie So what you are trying to do is pass a method as a parameter. You can use reflection to do that. But that's not recommended instead we use interface. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: Thanks I use intercase and it works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is probably to use Handlers and messages.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Or at least don't forget to run UI related code in UI thread via:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // code

        }
    });
```